# Background overlapping images at low resolution and when zooming in

Tags: html, css

I've attached screenshots of what is happening.  It appears on some browsers at low resolutions or when zooming in at the top and bottom right corners.  The only thing in my code that appears to be black is the background.  Why is this overlapping image.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  overflow: visible;
}

header {
  background-image: url('http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/Home-Background-2015.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 6;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}

.imgwedding {
  position: absolute;
  top: 97px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="imgwedding" class="mobile">
    <img border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/home.jpg" width="1100" height="649">
  </div>
```

Here is what it looks like without problems [Home](http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/homepagetest.jpg) and with black space covering bottom right corner [Home error](http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/homepagetesterror.jpg)

Comment: Are the navigation elements supposed to be a part of the background image?

Comment: yes, that is the way it is currently setup

Comment: So you're going to overlay elements on top of the image?

Comment: Yes, links are done with imagemaps and they size properly.  They are even clickable within the black space that is overlapping the image

Comment: Ouch! I would reconsider your approach. Definitely not best practice. I'm worried certain (valuable) information won't be accessible.